# Email Driven HTTP Requests Using Node.js & Express

Tags: node.js, email, http, express

In node.js express, one can set up server routes for your application based on http requests from an http client of any source - provided it is sent to the right resource on the right host. Example route might be:

```
application.post('/resource', function(request, response, next) {
    doThings();
    response.redirect('back');
});
```

Is there middleware that can be installed to set up routes for emails...? In my imagination this might look like:

```
application.email('resource@hostname.com', function(subject, body, attachment, next) {
    doThings();
    next();
});
```

Comment: Ya. So this might show a real misunderstanding about the way web servers and mail servers work and coexist but please forgive my ignorance. I know that the google app engine does something similar for other platforms - but I didn't see node listed.

Comment: Might want to check something like Haraka - http://haraka.github.io/manual/Tutorial.html which looks like a node-based extensible SMTP server.

Comment: http://blog.mailgun.com/handle-incoming-emails-like-a-pro-mailgun-api-2-0/